# Why doesn't Object.keys work as expected on the prototypes of String, Boolean, Number, and Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've noticed that when I try to use JavaScript's Object.keys method on the boxed primitive types' prototypes, the method returns an empty array. The following is code that shows that:

```
console.log(Object.keys(String.prototype)); // prints "[]"
// It prints the same thing for Object, Number, and Boolean.
```

Similarly, if I try to look at String.prototype or Object.prototype, I get the following:

```
console.log(String.prototype) // prints "[String: '']"
console.log(Object.prototype) // prints "{}"
```

To contrast this, here's how the Object.keys method works with a typical constructor and its prototype:

```
function MyList() {
  this.myList = [];
}
MyList.prototype.add = function(obj) {
  return this.myList.push(obj);
};

console.log(Object.keys(MyList.prototype)); // prints "[add]"
console.log(MyList.prototype); // prints "MyList { add: [Function] }"
```

Why are the prototypes of Object, Number, String, and Boolean blank, and why does Object.keys(Object.prototype) return nothing? Shouldn't these methods return references to all of these object's prototype methods and values, like toString() and valueOf() and whatever else is associated with these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` returns and objects "own" and "enumerable" properties.  String objects and other similar wrapped primitives don't have any enumerable properties.  So, `Object.keys()` is properly returning an empty array.

If you want to get the built-in "own" properties for a String, then you can do:

```
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)
```

Here's a demo:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype));
```

Or, if you want substantially more detail about the properties, you can use Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors() like this:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(String.prototype));
```